# Checkbox not selected based on database value

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes. These values are saved in db with comma like 1,2,3 (select three). In edit I want to select the three checkboxes. But it's not done.

**view**

```
<label class="control-label"> Select Group:</label>  </span>
<div class="controls">                                                
<span class="details">
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="1" <?php if(in_array('1', explode(",",$students_list->group_list))) echo( 'selected = "selected"'); ?> />one
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="2" <?php if(in_array('2', explode(",",$students_list->group_list))) echo( 'selected = "selected"'); ?>/>two
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="3" <?php if(in_array('3', explode(",",$students_list->group_list))) echo( 'selected = "selected"'); ?>/>three   
<?php echo form_error('group'); ?>
</span>
</div>
```

`$students_list->group_list` value like 1, 2, 3.

Comment: try using `"checked"` instead of `"selected="selected"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
echo( 'selected = "selected"');
```

to

```
echo( 'checked = "checked"');
```

and try again.